# xlsxwriter + Python looping over block for formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

So I am attempting to create a spreadsheet (.xlsx) to get some brownie points at work. I've not used python much but am picking it up slowly.

I would like to ask a question about a certain section in my code please...

In the below bunch of writes I have the following information to put into cells in the spreadsheet. This works like a charm but when I get to format some of the cells with 'bold' or 'underline' using xlsxwriter I am at a loss.

```
# This is the template of the xlsx file
worksheet2.write('A2', 'Scan Creation Date:')
worksheet2.write('A3', 'Total Hosts Scanned:')
worksheet2.write('A5', 'OVERALL FIGURES')
worksheet2.write('A6', 'Total Sev 5:')
worksheet2.write('A7', 'Total Sev 4:')
worksheet2.write('A8', 'Total Sev 3:')
worksheet2.write('A9', 'Total Sev 2:')
worksheet2.write('A10', 'Total Sev 1:')
worksheet2.write('A11', 'Overall Total:')
worksheet2.write('A13', 'Hostname')
worksheet2.write('B13', 'IP Address')
worksheet2.write('C13', 'Sev 5')
worksheet2.write('D13', 'Sev 4')
worksheet2.write('E13', 'Sev 3')
worksheet2.write('F13', 'Sev 2')
worksheet2.write('G13', 'Sev 1')
worksheet2.write('H13', 'Total')
worksheet2.write('I13', 'Stats (%)')
```

What I would like to do is reuse the above over and over again but append to each line with bold or underline or whatever I need to do to make it look pretty in the code.

```
# This is the template of the xlsx file
worksheet2.write('A2', 'Scan Creation Date:', bold)
worksheet2.write('A3', 'Total Hosts Scanned:', bold)
worksheet2.write('A5', 'OVERALL FIGURES', bold)
worksheet2.write('A6', 'Total Sev 5:', bold)
worksheet2.write('A7', 'Total Sev 4:')
worksheet2.write('A8', 'Total Sev 3:')
worksheet2.write('A9', 'Total Sev 2:')
worksheet2.write('A10', 'Total Sev 1:')
worksheet2.write('A11', 'Overall Total:', bold)
worksheet2.write('A13', 'Hostname', bold)
worksheet2.write('B13', 'IP Address')
worksheet2.write('C13', 'Sev 5', bold)
worksheet2.write('D13', 'Sev 4')
worksheet2.write('E13', 'Sev 3')
worksheet2.write('F13', 'Sev 2')
worksheet2.write('G13', 'Sev 1')
worksheet2.write('H13', 'Total')
worksheet2.write('I13', 'Stats (%)', bold)

    # This is the template of the xlsx file
worksheet2.write('A2', 'Scan Creation Date:', underline)
worksheet2.write('A3', 'Total Hosts Scanned:')
worksheet2.write('A5', 'OVERALL FIGURES', underline)
worksheet2.write('A6', 'Total Sev 5:')
worksheet2.write('A7', 'Total Sev 4:')
worksheet2.write('A8', 'Total Sev 3:')
worksheet2.write('A9', 'Total Sev 2:')
worksheet2.write('A10', 'Total Sev 1:')
worksheet2.write('A11', 'Overall Total:', underline)
worksheet2.write('A13', 'Hostname')
worksheet2.write('B13', 'IP Address')
worksheet2.write('C13', 'Sev 5')
worksheet2.write('D13', 'Sev 4')
worksheet2.write('E13', 'Sev 3')
worksheet2.write('F13', 'Sev 2')
worksheet2.write('G13', 'Sev 1')
worksheet2.write('H13', 'Total')
worksheet2.write('I13', 'Stats (%)')
```

So basically I can loop over each one and specify which I need to have the special formatting.

Also I forgot to mention that I tried playing around with zip to get them listed together and then attempt to add whatever I needed to each element it produces but then I saw it comes out as a 'tuple' so I cannot append to those.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can edit your post to add that information, there is an `edit` button at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 0):

One Way to do this would be to create a DataFrame containing all the different types of formats you would like to use in different columns.  You can then loop through a particular column using `pandas.DataFrame.iterrows()`.

I've provided an example below that uses a user-defined function with an argument based on the format column you want to use from the dataframe.

```
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
"cell": ['A2', 'A3', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'], 
"name": ['Scan Creation Date:', 'Total Hosts Scanned:', 
'OVERALL FIGURES', 'Total Sev 5:', 'Total Sev 5:'],
"format1": ['bold', 'none', 'bold', 'none', 'bold'],
"format2": ['underline', 'none', 'underline', 'none', 'none'],
"format3": ['underline', 'bold', 'underline', 'none', 'bold']
})

workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')

none = workbook.add_format({})
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,})
underline = workbook.add_format({'underline': True,})

def make_sheets(format_col):
    ws = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if df[''+ format_col +''].ix[i] == 'bold':
            format = bold
        elif df[''+ format_col +''].ix[i] == 'underline':
            format = underline
        else:
            format = none
        ws.write('%s' % (df['cell'].ix[i]), '%s' % (df['name'].ix[i]), 
format)

make_sheets("format1")
make_sheets("format2")
make_sheets("format3")

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image: Expected Output]